# Javascript Array[Variable] Reference Problems

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let string = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
let count = 0;
let part = string[count];
console.log(part); // logs out 'h'
count ++;
console.log(part); // still loggs out 'h'
```

I would like for the second log to log out 'e' instead of 'h'. Because I've updated code to 1 instead of 0.

Edit: I understand that I can just keep using the string[count] reference but I was asking if there was a way to do what I have described with a variable. (Make it reactive)

Comment: The variable `part` is not reactive. Meaning, you assigned `part` once, and it will stay as that value until you reassign `part`. It will not automatically update because you updated `count`.

Answer (score 1):

when you initialize part, you are setting it equal to 'h'. Despite incrementing count, that will not change part as it is still h. Thus, you will need to set part equal to string[count] again, after incrementing count.

```js
let string = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
let count = 0;
let part = string[count];
console.log(part); // logs out 'h'
count ++;
part = string[count];
console.log(part); // now logs 'e'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, Lex mentioned the main thing, I understand I have to do that but was wondering if there was another way of doing it by using a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `part` a function, then call it whenever you want to get the item at index `count`:

```js
let string = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
let count = 0;
let part = () => string[count];
console.log(part());
count ++;
console.log(part());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it dynamic based off counter don't create the part reference.

```js
let string = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
let count = 0;
console.log(string[count]) // logs out 'h'
count ++
console.log(string[count])
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that would work, but I had to reference string[count] a lot and different variations such as string[count + 1]. So it just seemed easier to create a variable to take out the hassle. I ended up doing what you said with a simple F2 keystrong in VS code